# Escape Special Character in Regex

Tags: c#, regex, escaping

Is there a way to escape the special characters in regex, such as `[]()*` and others,  from a string?

Basically, I'm asking the user to input a string, and I want to be able to search in the database using regex. Some of the issues I ran into are `too many)'s` or `[x-y] range in reverse order`, etc.

So what I want to do is write a function to do replace on the user input. For example, replacing `(` with `\(`, replacing `[` with `\[`

Is there a built-in function for regex to do so? And if I have to write a function from scratch, is there a way to account all characters easily instead of writing the replace statement one by one?

I'm writing my program in C# using Visual Studio 2010

Comment: A Google search on *C# escape special character regex* returns the answer.

Comment: It can be argued the user has to enter correct RE in the first place. You cant just escape random character if you dont know if it is a special character or not. (Unless you don't want the user to enter RE of course, but then the questin is why would you use RE for the query).

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can use .NET's built in [Regex.Escape](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape(v=vs.110).aspx) for this. Copied from Microsoft's example:

```
string pattern = Regex.Escape("[") + "(.*?)]"; 
string input = "The animal [what kind?] was visible [by whom?] from the window.";

MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);
int commentNumber = 0;
Console.WriteLine("{0} produces the following matches:", pattern);
foreach (Match match in matches)
   Console.WriteLine("   {0}: {1}", ++commentNumber, match.Value);  

// This example displays the following output: 
//       \[(.*?)] produces the following matches: 
//          1: [what kind?] 
//          2: [by whom?]
```

Answer (score 9):

you can use  [Regex.Escape](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for the user's input

Answer (score -1):

```
string matches = "[]()*";
StringBuilder sMatches = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder regexPattern = new StringBuilder();
for(int i=0; i<matches.Length; i++)
    sMatches.Append(Regex.Escape(matches[i].ToString()));
regexPattern.AppendFormat("[{0}]+", sMatches.ToString());

Regex regex = new Regex(regexPattern.ToString());
foreach(var m in regex.Matches("ADBSDFS[]()*asdfad"))
    Console.WriteLine("Found: " + m.Value);
```

Comment: That's a lot of unnecessary work to create an incorrect result.